# What properties of profunctors do not make it into Haskell/PureScript?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, purescript, category-theory, profunctor

In their paper on [profunctor optics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10857), Pickering et al. state that

> The term ‘profunctor’ comes from category theory, although much of the categorical structure gets lost in translation.

That seems odd and kind of unique to me, as other algebraic structures I know of (pairs, monoids, functors, categories, etc.) "do not seem" to suffer the same fate, in languages like Haskell and PureScript – with quotes because I'm happy to be proven wrong.

A while ago, I played a bit with the family of profunctors and found them very tractable, especially in the context of optics. My interest got picked again after seeing them come up [in the context of monad transformers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bxcz23GOJqc). I need to rewatch this a couple of times as I don't get the details, but on principle it is perfectly clear. So I can't help wondering:

- what are those properties? why don't they materialise in the language?
- what effort would be necessary to bring them in, if at all possible?
- what would be the benefits of doing so? In particular, could they help solve the issues Ed mentions at the end of his talk?

Comment: Well... at the very least functors and monads are quite restricted, in that they are only endofunctors on Hask.  There are other categories, even in haskell, worth considering, but our `Monad` does not capture them.

Comment: I see. Although I know endofunctors map a category to itself, I have a very limited view on what it prevents us from doing (is that what Conal Eliott's paper "Compiling to categories" is all about?). I guess my question is, even with that limitation, do Haskell functors keep their algebraic properties?

Comment: One limitation is that profunctor laws cannot be expressed in Haskell. A profunctor maps pairs of morphisms -- in Haskell that's the purpose of dimap -- and it should map identity morphisms to identities, and composition to composition. You can check these laws by hand using equational reasoning. 

Then there is the fact that profunctors form a category. Natural transformations between profunctors may be approximated by polymorphic functions but, in Haskell, they are restricted by parametricity. Optics, in particular, require polymorphism over profunctor categories with various constraints.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve read your “profunctors as relations” post, it provided good food for thought; I’ll need to re-read a few times, as some statements still escape me. Especially since, if they form a category, I should be able to write an instance of Category for any Profunctor. I’ll try to write one and see where that leads me.

Comment: @RegisKuckaertz profunctors form a category, where composition is https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.3/docs/Data-Profunctor-Composition.html; **not** every `Profunctor` is a `Category` (many  are though, but e.g. `Tagged` cannot be, there is no `id`). Various classes -- like `Strong` -- form sub-categories, there is e.g. `(Strong p, Strong q) => Strong (Procompose p q)` instance: profunctor optics use these sub-category classes to form various optics.